# Doctrine manyToOne on another indexe than ID

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, relationship, database-indexes

I have an Entity A with oneToMany B
Entity A :

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="A",  indexes={
*     @ORM\index(name="uid", columns={"uid"}),
* })
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ARepository")
*/
class A
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="uid", type="string", length=50, unique=true)
 */
private $uid;

/**
 * ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\B",mappedBy="a",cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
private $b;

// Guetters and setters ...
```

And Entity B

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="B")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BRepository")
*/
class B
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;  

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\A",inversedBy="b")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="uid",name="a_uid")
 */
private $a;  

// Guetters and setters ...
```

I try to do :

```
$A = new A();
$B->setA($A);
```

I persist them. And when I flush, I have this error :

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
Notice: Undefined index: uid
```

I really dont know what to do, it seems I have a Indexes problem... (?) Any help is welcome

Update :

If I add `@ORM\Id` on $uid and I remove `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")` it works when I manually set the A.id field...
I'm getting closer to the goal ! ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing uid from class A as the referenceColumn for the relation, which is a nullable field. change it to

`/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\A",inversedBy="b")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id",name="a_id")
 */
private $a;`

or make the uid nullable false. As the uid data is unique, also consider making uid as the primary key for class A.